# Speed of using SQL temp table vs long list of variables in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, variables, temp-tables

I have a stored procedure with a list of about 50 variables of different types repeated about 8 times as part of different groups (declaration, initialization, loading, calculations, result, e.t.c.).

In order to avoid duplication I want to use temp tables instead (not table variable, which does not bring advantages that I seek - inferred type).

I've read that temp tables may start as "in memory table" and then are spilled to disk as they grow depending on amount of memory and many other conditions.

My question is - if I use temp table to store and manipulate one record with 50 fields, will it be much slower than using 50 variables ?

Comment: can you show part of query ?are using variable in where condition ?how are you using it ?

Comment: ok, there is query with where condition that uses one of those variables like select tbl.id, ... from tbl join tbl2 ... where tbl.id = @id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use a temp #Table unless I need to store temporary results for multiple rows.  Our code uses lots of variables in some stored procedures.  The ability to initialize during declaration helps reduce clutter.

Temp #Tables have some interesting side effects with regards to query compilation.  If your stored procedure calls any child procedures, and queries in the child procs refer to this #Table, then these queries will be recompiled upon every execution.

Also, note that if you modify the temp #Table schema in any way, then SQL Server will not be able to cache the table definition.  You'll be incurring query recompilation penalties in every query that refers to the table.  Also, SQL Server will hammer various system tables as it continually creates and drops the table metadata.

On the other hand, if you don't call child procs, and you don't change the #Table schema, it might perform OK.

But stylistically, it does not make sense to me to add another join to a query just to get a variable for use in a `WHERE` clause.  In other words, I'd rather see a lot of this:

```
declare @id

select @id = ...

select tbl.id, ...
from tbl
inner join tbl2 ...
where tbl.id = @id
```

Instead of this:

```
create table #VarTbl (...)

insert into #VarTbl (...) select ...

select tbl.id, ...
from tbl
inner join tbl2 ...
cross join #VariableTable
where tbl.id = VarTbl_ID
```

Another thought: can you break apart the stored procedure into logical groups of operations?  That might help readability.  It can also help reduce query recompilations.  If one child proc needs to be recompiled, this will not affect the parent proc or other child procs.

Comment: I was not going to use create table #VarTbl (...), I wanted to use select id=... into #VarTbl, which allows to create temp table with properly inferred types (except modifiable varchars, which have to be explicitly specified to set sufficient size). Will this cause query recomppilations ?

Comment: Yes, I believe `SELECT INTO` will cause recompilations.  The format of the resulting #VarTbl is not known in advance by the SQL optimizer.  Therefore SQL Server cannot cache the type, and any queries that reference it will have to be recompiled at runtime.

Comment: Is cost of runtime recompilation significant compared to execution ?

Comment: The answer depends on the amount of data.  Recompilation of a single query might take between 1 and 10 ms to generate a plan.  If your query taks several seconds to complete, then no, it's probably not significant.  If the query takes 1 ms, that might be significant.  If your query takes 1 ms and there are hundreds or thousands of them running every second, then it is extremely significant.  But an equally important issue is the tempdb table churn.  Creating and destroying the temp #Tables takes time and can cause blocking on system metadata tables.  We've seen this cause deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not be much slower; you would probably even have a hard time showing it is slower at all in normal use cases.

I always use temp tables in this instance; the performance difference is negligible and readability and ease of use is better in my opinion. I normally start looking at using a temp table if I get above 10 variables, especially if those are related.